# Need for Complex Sort Criteria Views

Tags: views

I have a challenging task of making an HTML List into a View within Drupal.

The original list is alphabetical EXCEPT for the first 40 entries which are organized essentially in chronological order as well as most popular items on top.

I believe i took care of the most popular items (5 of them) buy utilizing the sticky option within Drupal.

The next 35 items... 30 of them need to be organized by the release date, in this case a "special event #" in the node title is what is used to signify its chronological order.

Example:

```
 Cool Party - Special Event 1
 Fun Shindig - Special Event 2
 Quiet Gathering - Special Event 3
 Funny Picnic - Special Event 4
```

I want to know how i can sort the list within Views to get the special event listings in order from 1-30 at the top of my list (just after the sticky top 5)

Answer (score 1):

You are able to create a single block or page in views with **different sort criteria** using **attachments** in views

[image]

- So create a view with some criteria and add an attachment like above and override the sort criteria as you need
- Then add your attachment to your page or block as below

[image]

Here is a [post](http://nmc-codes.blogspot.in/2012/10/views-attachment-in-drupal-7.html) which explains this in detail.

Comment: I should be clear i am using a Views Table for this. Will your solution still work when using tables?

Comment: Yes changing the format doesn't affect things

Comment: Is there a way to wrap it all so it looks like one table instead of two?

Comment: Adding an attachment and removing its title make it look like a single page.. pls jump in and try it.. It might give you some idea..